# Как из Jquery изменить объект Angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Добрый день.
Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую срабатывает код Jquery, и он должен изменить параметры в контроллере angularjs.
Как такое сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

По возможности перенесите этот код в контроллер и повешайте событие на кнопку через "ng-click", если какая-то хитронамудренная специфика, то тут по коду нужно смотреть и, как вариант, директиву для этого сделать.